# Теряется качество изображения при сохранении с помощью html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Всем привет. подскажите пожалуйста, где моя ошибка. Задача состоит в том, чтобы сохранить блок в виде изображения. Делаю это следующим образом:

```html
html2canvas($('.gameTable'),{
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
        $('#download').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"));
    $('#download').attr('download', prefix+'_'+type+'_'+size+'.png');
    $('#download')[0].click();
  }
});
```

Пробовал и так:

```html
html2canvas($('.gameTable'), {
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
    var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          newCanvas.setAttribute('width',1000);
          newCanvas.setAttribute('height',1000);
          var ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
          ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height,0,0,1000,1000);
          var dataURL = newCanvas.toDataURL();
          var img = $(document.createElement('img'));
          img.attr('src', dataURL);
          $('#download').attr('href', newCanvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
    $('#download').attr('download', prefix+'_'+type+'_'+size+'.png');
    $('#download')[0].click();
  }
});
```

В результате получаю изображение плохого качества, во всяком случае, заказчик недоволен.
Вот сохраненный скриптов вариант:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сохраненный с помощью Lightshot:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя я сейчас смотрю на прикрепленные изображения и особых различий не вижу, скажите, может есть в моих действиях какая-то ошибка. Всем заранее благодарен.

Comment: Возможно есть какой-то другой способ сохранения определенного блока страницы, не обязательно с помощью jQuery. Подойдет любой способ сохраняющий изображение средствами браузера.

Comment: Загрузил на хост тестовую версию http://mastertest.xyz/chess/ . Изображение сохраняется при клике на кнопку "1000 px", так думаю будет нагляднее видна потеря качества изображения.

Comment: Какой оригинальный размер картинки? Можете оригинал выложить. То что сохранили вы своим скриптом и Lightshot разницы не вижу

Comment: mastertest.xyz/chess попробуйте тут, если Вам не сложно, так отличие видно четко.

Comment: Блок который должен быть сохранен имеет размер в 1000х1000 пикселей. И изображение получаю такого же размера.

Comment: Вы пробовали сделать http://mastertest.xyz/chess/img/pieces_2/board_bw_1.png эту картинку чуть больше чем 1000px? а в канвасе размер подогнать под 1000

Comment: Стоп. canvas.toDataURL(type, encoderOptions);

Comment: второй параметр это качество

Comment: Можно источник, где Вы это нашли или подскажите в каких единицах устанавливается?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: попробовал canvas.toDataURL("image/png",0.5) и оно как то лучше стало :)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ehscwi

Comment: Согласен с Вами. Спасибо Вам огромное. Как-то я упустил данный момент, так как смотрел больше на готовые примеры в которых почему-то не применялся второй параметр. Пожалуй это и есть ответ на мой вопрос. Как тут это можно отметить?

Comment: сейчас ответ напишу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

соглано MDN метод канваса toDataURL имеет второй параметр качество:

canvas.toDataURL(type, encoderOptions);

> encoderOptions - Число от 0 до 1, указывающее качество изображения.

Так же у этого параметра

> Значение по умолчанию - 0,92.

можно, например, поставить canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1)